# How to make 2 videos in HTML5 overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I would like to make 1 HTML5 video overlap over another video?  Basically I want to add a moving object (a video) over my background video. Please help me in achieving this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been struggling with a similar issue myself over the past couple days, and though I can't tell you exactly how to do it I can share what I have learned and hopefully get you a better starting point.
HTML5 Video and HTML5 canvas elements have some interesting interactions with each other now, in that you can take your videos and draw them onto a canvas element using the  `drawimage()` method with the HTML5 Video element as the source.

To overlap the videos you could create a Canvas Element and using the `drawimage()` draw both videos onto the Canvas.

Check out this tutorial on HTML5 Video Manipulation [here](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/)
Check out a demo of putting a HTML5 Video (among other things) over top another video [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~prouget/demos/DynamicContentInjection/play.xhtml)

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to define different z-index values in css.

HTML

```
<video class="video-one"> ...</video>
<video class="video-two"> ...</video>
```

CSS, where the second video overlaps the first one.

```
.video-one { z-index: 1 } /* optional */
.video-two { z-index: 2 }
```